# How can I manage array index?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

My question about arrays. I have arrays:

```
var orderItemName = [String]()

["halimiz duman aman", "halimiz duman aman", "halimiz duman aman", "halimiz duman aman", "halimiz duman aman", "halimiz duman aman", "burada da urun var", "burada da urun var", "burada da urun var", "urunler burdadir", "urunler burdadir", "urunler burdadir", "urunler burdadir", "urunler burdadir"]

var orderItemPrice = [String]()

["14 ₺", "14 ₺", "14 ₺", "14 ₺", "14 ₺", "14 ₺", "425 ₺", "425 ₺", "425 ₺", "32 ₺", "32 ₺", "32 ₺", "32 ₺", "32 ₺"]

var arrays = [String: Int]() 

["halimiz duman aman": 6, "urunler burdadir": 5, "burada da urun var": 3]

var arraysPrice = [String: Int]()

["425 ₺": 3, "14 ₺": 6, "32 ₺": 5]
```

I want to get coupled arrays and arraysPrice from their values and I want to get arrays.keys according to correct index. When I try to make it arrays.keys will appear wrong order. (because it is arranged in the order shown above.) Can anyone help me? I hope I can ask clearly.

Comment: Your `arrays` is not an array. It is a dictionary. Also your `arraysPrice` is a dictionary.  Dictionaries have no order. The order in which it prints out is meaningless. It has no order and no index.

Comment: @matt you are right I confused. How can I solve it ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you mean. There is nothing to solve.

Comment: please tell what you want to output in 4 input values ..??

Comment: @kishansuthar I have to make order page for my app and I have to take item's names, item's prices and item's count. My code can do correct counts and prices but in item's names appear with different item's price and count place. I hope I explain clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to structs. Otherwise this will continue to bite you.

```
struct Item {
    let name: String
    let price: String // Should be a Currency type, but matching your code
}

let items = [
    Item(name: "halimiz duman aman", price: "14 ₺"),
    Item(name: "halimiz duman aman", price: "14 ₺"),
    Item(name: "halimiz duman aman", price: "14 ₺"),
    Item(name: "halimiz duman aman", price: "14 ₺"),
    Item(name: "halimiz duman aman", price: "14 ₺"),
    Item(name: "halimiz duman aman", price: "14 ₺"),
    ...
    ]
```

If you happen to have two arrays (I would avoid ever creating them, but if you have them from something else like a server response), then you can convert these into a struct by "zipping":

```
let orders = zip(orderItemName, orderItemPrice).map(Item.init)
```

To "zip" two arrays is to take one item from each, and make them a tuple `(String, String)`. That is then passed to `Item.init`. When either array runs out, then the zip stops (so if they're different lengths, then some items may be ignored). This `map` code is logically the same as:

```
var orders: [Item] = []
for (name, price) in zip(orderItemName, orderItemPrice) {
    orders.append(Item(name: name, price: price))
}
```

With that you can compute the counts you're looking for. For example:

```
func count(name: String, in items: [Item]) {
    return items.filter(where: { $0.name == name }).count
}
```

You can create the specific dictionary you're looking for by counting all the names at once.

```
func nameCounts(from items: [Item]) -> [String: Int] {
    var result: [String: Int] = [:]

    for item in items {
        result[item.name, default: 0] += 1
    }

    return result
}
```

Or in a slightly more fancy way:

```
func nameCounts(from items: [Item]) -> [String: Int] {
    return items.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.name, default: 0] += 1 }
}
```

The key lesson here is that you should put all the data that relates to a single thing in a struct, and then have an array of those structs. Don't spread it out over multiple arrays.

---

For future learning (this is possibly too advanced for where you are), the above can be made very generic like this:

```
extension Sequence  {
    func counts<Value: Hashable>(of keyPath: KeyPath<Element, Value>) -> [Value: Int] {
        return self.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1[keyPath: keyPath], default: 0] += 1 }
    }
}
```

This permits you to do things like:

```
items.counts(of: \.name)
items.counts(of: \.price)
```

But you shouldn't worry too much about this kind of generic code when you're getting started. The first `for...in` code is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to ask one thing more I have two arrays. One of them give items names and other items price how I can add struct to these arrays?

Comment: Exactly as described at the start. Do not have two arrays. Have a single array with two properties. Managing two synchronized arrays is very difficult and you will constantly have bugs because it's hard to think about. Don't do that.

Comment: (But also updated in how you can turn existing arrays into a struct using `zip`)